# Context Menu event with QGraphicsWidget

Tags: c++, qt, events, qt4, contextmenu

In my application I subclass QGraphicsWidget
In paint I am drawing a line with pen width 4.
I reimplemented boundingRect() and shape().
But I can't catch context menu event every time I click right mouse button.
What is the problem.(Pen Width ? )

```
 //Sample code for boundingRect() and shape()
  QRectF boundingRect() const
  {
    qreal rectLeft = x1 < x2 ? x1 : x2;
    qreal rectTop = y1 < y2 ? y1 : y2;
    qreal rectWidth = (x1 - x2) != 0 ? abs(x1-x2) : 4;
    qreal rectHeight = (y1 - y2) != 0 ? abs(y1 -y2) : 4;

    return QRectF(rectLeft,rectTop,rectWidth,rectHeigt);
  }

  QPainterPath shape()
  {
    QPainterPath path;
    path.addRect(boundingRect());
    return path;
  }
```

Comment: hello, you QGraphicView object is transparent? Where are you implementing the mouceClickEvent? Give me a little more of information.

Comment: cnebrera is right, your code does not show any code related to handling mouse events. Be a little more specific. Afaik, you need to reimplement `QWidget::contextMenuEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also reimplement `QWidget::mousePressEvent()`, check if only rightMouseButton as pressed and call your method, where you will show your QMenu manually.